# where am i wrong in my calculation?why is \$V_{bc}=220∠120°-120°=220∠0°\$,not \$V_{bc}=220∠-120°-(120°)=220∠-240°\$

Tags: three-phase

A three-phase Y circuit with positive sequence (abc),now if \$V_{ab}=220∠120°\$,then what is\$V_{bc}\$,and \$V_{ca}\$ ?

i thought Y circuit with positive sequence means \$V_{ao}=220∠0°, V_{bo}=220∠-120°,V_{co}=220∠-240°=220∠120°\$,so \$V_{ab}=220∠0°-(-120°)=220∠120°\$,so obviously

\$V_{bc}=220∠-120°-(120°)=220∠-240°\$

\$V_{ca}=220∠120°-(0°)=220∠120°\$

However,the solution for this problem is

\$V_{bc}=220∠120°-120°=220∠0°\$

\$V_{ca}=220∠120°+120°=220∠240°\$

So it seems that my answer are all wrong,so i want to ask where am i wrong in my calculation?

Comment: It tells you what \$V_{ab}\$ is, so why have you decided to calculate it as something else?

Answer (score 1):

> *if Vab=220∠120°,then what isVbc,and Vca ?*

[image]

For a positive phase sequence Vbc will have a zero angle and Vca will have an angle of -240 degrees.

Where you appear to be going wrong is trying to fit your thinking to a scenario when Vab is at zero degrees. Yes, the reference phase angle is usually defined along the horizontal right-hand axis but, it can be redefined for any angle providing that the sequence direction is respected. That new reference is defined in the question as a phase of 120 degrees.

Comment: why isn't \$V_{ca}\$ in the position of \$V_{bc}\$?

Comment: The phase sequence is positive and (accordingly) the phasors rotate anti-clockwise hence, once Vab has passed a reference point, the next voltage to pass that reference point will be Vbc and finally it will be Vca. Hence, starting at Vac's line in the picture above and remembering that they rotate anti-clockwise, the next phasor to reach peak amplitude is Vbc.

Comment: Because as i know,the positive sequence is just like the sequence of phase voltage,like \$V_{an}\$,\$V_{bn}\$ and \$V_{cn}\$,but \$V_{ab}\$, \$V_{bc}\$ and  \$V_{ca}\$ is like a line voltage,how do i know the sequence of line voltage is  \$V_{ab}\$, \$V_{bc}\$ and  \$V_{ca}\$,not  \$V_{ab}\$, \$V_{ca}\$ and  \$V_{bc}\$?

Comment: Look at pg 13 in this slide show: https://slideplayer.com/slide/10648019/. Then look at pg 25 to see how they convert Vxn voltages to line voltages and you will see that line voltages are 30 degrees ahead of their respective phase voltage i.e. Vab leads Van by 30 degrees.